# SUBSTRING does not limit string length. Specified 32, got 256

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlcmd

Why does this query result in node names of 256 characters? I have applied SUBSTRING() to limit it to 32.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NodeName),1,32) AS NODENAME
    ,LEN(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NodeName),1,32))
    ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')),1,32) AS CURRENT_OWNER
FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes;
```

**UPDATE:**

The data will come from the machine this query is running on. Here is the result. I would like for the lines not to exceed the screen width. I am trying to limit the names to 32 characters.

```
PS C:\> sqlcmd -S DBINSTANCENAME
1> SELECT
2>     SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NodeName),1,32) AS NODENAME
3>     ,LEN(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NodeName),1,32))
4>     ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')),1,32) AS CURRENT_OWNER
5> FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes;
6> GO
NODENAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              CURRENT_OWNER                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ANODESQL78D                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    15 TX102WPD2SQL78C                                                                                                                                                       
ANODESQL78C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    15 TX102WPD2SQL78C                                                                                                                                                       

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Seems like the length is 15, so not even close to your limit. The problem must be in how the data is visualised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you've got a `CONVERT` in there which is changing the column to a `varchar(MAX)`. When using `SUBSTRING` on a `varchar(MAX)` the return data type is a `varchar(MAX)`. `MAX` length data is treated as a different data type to a numerical length, and SQL Server won't implicitly convert between the 2 when there's no other data type involved.

The solution is simple, don't `CONVERT` the value to a `MAX` length:

```sh
thom@ptah:~$ sqlcmd -Q "SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(256), NodeName),1,32) AS NODENAME, LEN(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(256), NodeName),1,32)) ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')),1,32) AS CURRENT_OWNER FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes;"
NODENAME                                     CURRENT_OWNER                   
-------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------

(0 rows affected)
```

Comment: or convert it to varchar(32)

Comment: I was unable to duplicate the issue. Do you know of any documentation that might describe why it's returning 256 chars, other than just, "[...] treated as a different datatype?"

Comment: *"I was unable to duplicate the issue"* It's very simple to do, @TimLehner: [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94f58454864bc3f7fe6a74fd31876b04)

Comment: In regards to `varchar(MAX)`, SQL server stores these differently to columns defined as a with a numerical length. Like I mentioned, SQL Server does *not* implicitly convert between `MAX` and non-`MAX` length values as it would have severe performance impacts if so. Also, when concatenating, unless at least one of those values is a `MAX` type the value will be truncated at 8,000 bytes; this would be a problem if the above `SUBSTRING` was being concatenated to other non-`MAX` values which would end up in over 8,000 bytes.

Comment: @Larnu that example still doesn't seem to duplicate the OP's result, nor does your technical explanation seem to indicate why they would get 256 rather than any other length.

Comment: @TimLehner What do mean it doesn't... Yes it does. The OP is getting a `nvarchar(MAX)` from the data. The reason it's 256 characters wide in the CLI is because sqlcmd truncates the columns to 256 characters wide; that doesn't change the returned data type...

Comment: If you don't believe this, try `sqlcmd -Q "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX),'');"` You'll get 256 hyphens (`-`).

Answer (score 1):

The [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) has a default value of 256 for the scripting variable `SQLCMDMAXVARTYPEWIDTH` It will give a column header width based on the max width of the returned datatype up to this limit.

[`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) returns the same datatype as the input expression -- `varchar(max)` in your case -- with a few exceptions.

My guess is that you have not set this option, so you're getting 256 character headers for any character datatypes larger than that. [You can change it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables) with the `-y` option in your command. Similarly, if you're running in SQL Server Management Studio, use the SSMS Options dialog:

`Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text > "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column:"`

@Larnu's end solution is still correct, though: either implicitly or explicitly cast or convert columns to your desired output width if it is important, but beware of the limits set for your tool's output.